# Ubuntu 23.04 - Change save-as dialog

Tags: ubuntu, gtk

I want to change the "save as" dialog in Ubuntu 23.04. I use gnome-flashback.

- observed behaviour: If I type e.g. "vi" then it shows only the folders that contain the * string "vi" (case insensitive). No folder is selected.
- desired behaviour: select the first folder whose name starts with "vi" (case insensitive).

In other words, I want it to behave like the nemo file manager, not like nautilus (in their default settings).

I read that it's somehow connected to gtk+ settings. But can someone tell me exactly what to change and where?